# Add trailing slash wit url excluding some urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have used the following rule to add trailing slash with url and its working fine

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myexamplesite.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I want to exclude some admin urls and some ajax urls so that they dont permanent redirect, I tried with following code but its not working

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !get-ajax
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myexamplesite.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

There are some more urls I want to exclude from trailing slash ( means they can be loaded with or without trailing slash ) 
Above code works only for one url like get-ajax but not for all, there will be some more urls I will exclude form trailing slash.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: "but its now working" - presumably you mean "not working"? The above should also work for `admin`? If you add more URLs, are these not excluded? Your code looks OK so there may be a conflict with other directives?

Comment: yes sometimes it works properly but i can see that some urls still redirecting to trailing slash even if they match the criteria. I am trying to debug it dont know how to do it

Comment: Do these URLs that "don't work" correspond to physical directories? In such cases mod_dir will automatically append a trailing slash before mod_rewrite gets a chance to act on the URL. You should enable mod_rewrite logging - this requires access to your server config and depends whether you are using Apache 2.2 or 2.4. And make sure your browser cache is cleared.